# Use of the subjunctive in answering questions

Tags: interrogative

I am working through some lessons and the guide has the following exchanges:

```
Velisne libum? Velim.

Visne libum? Volo.
```

So the guide seems to be expecting that if the question is put in the optative subjunctive, then it should be answered in the subjunctive, but if the question only uses an interrogatory enclitic, then the answer should be in the indicative. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guess than an answer, but here goes.

Both *velisne libum* (would you like a cake) and *visne libum* (do you want a cake) are yes-no questions. Latin famously lacks exact equivalents for yes and no, and so we just repeat the main verb in the question.

Responding to *velisne libum* with *volo* (Would you like a cake? I do.) would be a little weird, just like my English translation in parentheses sounds a bit off. Likewise, "Do you want a cake? I would" sounds a bit off, incomplete even, with an implied "but" left unsaid.